# How to paginate a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, pagination

I have this **foreach loop** wich shows **the supporters** located in the **post_meta** from a custom post type. What I want to do is add **pagination** to the foreach loop. I have already found a way to decide how many supporters are shown by slicing the array, but now I am at a loss. And have no idea how to proceed.

Function to get the **supporters array**

```
function getSupporters($petitieID){
$support = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'supporters', true);

if (!empty($support)){
    return $support;
}}
```

Function to show the **individual supporters in the array**

```
function showSupporters($petitieID){

$supporters = getSupporters($petitieID);
if (!empty($supporters)){
    foreach (array_slice($supporters, 0, 2) as $supporter){

    $supporterID = $supporter->post_author;
        the_author_meta('first_name', $supporterID);
    }

}else {

    echo    'no votes';
}
}
```

Comment: I would go for a client side (js) pagination rather then server-side (php) since you are already dealing with your entire set of data ($supporters).

Comment: You can find complete solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145259/simple-pagination-for-foreach-loop Thanks
Netbros

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could determine which page is currently shown in a GET variable in your address

```
.../supporters.php?page=1
```

Then you could set the offset of your `array_slice` function accordingly

```
$nItemsPerPage = 2;
$page = isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:1;
array_slice($supporters, $nItemsPerPage*($page-1), $nItemsPerPage)
```